# Pandas giving a SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to convert a string into a date field in a pandas data frame.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%d%b%Y')
```

But I got warning:

```
C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:17: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I cannot understand much from the documentation. What exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: is df a sub-selection of a larger dataframe? In that case that sub-selection is still linked to the larger dataframe and you are not just changing a column of df, but also trying to change the slice of that bigger dataframe.
Easy solution, wherever you define df = bigger_df[ix:ix] use: df = bigger_df[ix:ix].copy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to something happening earlier in your code; presumably you have defined `df` as a subset of a larger dataframe, either directly as a slice (as the error message suggests) or via something like `df = big_df[big_df[col] == 'A']`. The warning is telling you that your original dataframe will also be changed by this action. To avoid this, use `.copy()` when you're generating a dataframe as a slice or a subset of a larger one.